# What's the right C++ GUI library for making an interface for an already written console app?

Tags: c++, user-interface, interface, console

I am currently writting a c++ console app with libraries such as iostream, algorithm and cstring, but in the future I would like to add an UI to it, mostly buttons and input fields.
I am looking for a (commercially) free library that will allow me to simply add an interface on top of what I have already written, a one where communicating and passing data is easy, and one where I don't have to rewrite most of my program's logic using the GUI's functions for the interface to work.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no silver bullet; your application will have to be written to accommodate swapping out the user interface. If you put `std::cin >> x` in your program **no GUI library** can provide a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Split the project into 2 layers (logical modules) processing and input/output and don't mix the two.  Then you can just replace the input/output layer with GUI code and call the unchanged processing code.

Comment: @botje well, technically someone could write a replacement cin/cout that creates a window, display stuff and allow user-input. It would be a crappy UI and not offer much more than the console, but "no GUI library can provide a drop-in" may be an over statement.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's just that I have been looking for a good easy library for so long, I lost all motivation, when I started coding it in the console, I was so happy that I actually made progress, as I knew what I was doing. I just find it rather annoying that I have to change so much just to create a couple of buttons

Comment: Here I describe an app which I developed first in the console, then I added a simple UI (with wxwidgets): https://compphys.go.ro/dft-for-an-atom/ stdout is simply redirected into an edit box (actually a rich text control if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend wxWidgets, it's easy to use. It uses the platform's native API and also free.

Comment: Hello and welcome! This is actually a nice answer, but lacks a bit of research into the reqirements of the OP. These kind of questions are better to be redirected to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/